# Representation of a chemical bond as an arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, chemfig

With which options and above all where can the head of the arrow (coordinative bond) be designed (e.g. triangle as head)? This should be possible with TikZ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*5(--N(-[,1.5,,,->]Co)---)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what "*coordinative*" bonds are, but note note that according to IUPAC recommendations *dative* bonds (looks like what you are trying to draw) *must not* be used to represent coordination (see https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277, p. 292).

Comment: @ andselisk Thanks a lot. A coordinative bond is a dative bond.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{*5(--N(-[,1.5,,,-Stealth,dashed]Co)---)}
\end{document}
```

In the fifth position you can pass TikZ arguments to `chemfig` allowing you to alter the shape of the bound or arrow in this case.

[image]

Comment: @ alchemist Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.